# How can I make an image's height dependent on the other content inside of a div?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a fixed height and a content area that can have different amounts of text. I need the image to change its height(the image can be cropped) so that everything fills the fixed height of the div.

[Examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYW8o.jpg)

Comment: use the image as background

Comment: What have you tried so far?? Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
  background-image: url('/assets/img/cookie.jpg');
}

div.container>textarea {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <textarea>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam hendrerit rutrum finibus. Quisque tincidunt laoreet justo eget posuere. Quisque gravida imperdiet elit, ac volutpat tortor tempor placerat. Sed aliquam, metus ac vulputate varius, arcu diam pulvinar tortor, vel congue massa odio sed sem. Fusce auctor neque non nisl lobortis, nec vehicula nulla malesuada. Vestibulum pellentesque odio tempus, tincidunt augue hendrerit, venenatis libero. Pellentesque convallis luctus rutrum. Nunc vel mauris sit amet nibh laoreet hendrerit vitae vel tellus. Phasellus gravida dui ac venenatis aliquet.

      Proin pulvinar pellentesque lorem, a imperdiet massa pulvinar eget. Quisque vitae est lorem. Maecenas porttitor quis dui sit amet ultricies. Phasellus accumsan, augue ac ornare tincidunt, eros diam sollicitudin enim, id vehicula quam justo quis leo. Aliquam at turpis est. Praesent rutrum felis eget justo suscipit finibus et nec enim. Quisque sed eleifend velit, eget fringilla purus. Nunc imperdiet metus luctus laoreet porttitor.
    </textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xBGNeX

Answer (score 1):

You can use a grid for that (I just did that yesterday at work hahah), something like:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  height: 400px;
  grid-template-rows: auto min-content;
}

img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img />
  <p>....</p>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gEpJZZ

You can also use flex:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 400px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use flexbox. Flexbox allow you to set what element will be have more place than other.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  background: green;
  width: 20%;
}

.child:nth-child(1) {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">gwert sdg sdg qwe gw asdasda sd asd a`sd asd asd asdf asdf asdf ar gwert sdg sdg qwe gw asdasda sd asd a`sd asd asd asdf asdf asdf a gwert sdg sdg qwe gw asdasda sd asd a`sd asd asd asdf asdf asdf a</div>
  <div class="child"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snowtops.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```